# Errors when importing a project from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, import, gradle, android-studio

Tried to leave the Eclipse IDE for Android Studio so i downloaded and imported my project in it.
Android Studio had messed up with the Greek encoding in the java files but replaced them from the start, so no issue here.
Tried to run the project (since it was already error free in Eclipse) and I get this:

```
D:\Programming\EortologioReloadedAS\eortologioReloaded\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:27:9 Error:
    Attribute application@label value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml:27:9
    is also present at EortologioReloadedAS:wheel:unspecified:11:18 value=(Android Wheel Widget)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at     AndroidManifest.xml:25:5 to override

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':eortologioReloaded:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml:27:9
is also present at EortologioReloadedAS:wheel:unspecified:11:18 value=(Android Wheel Widget)
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5 to override

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Can't understand what exactly the problem is.

This Gradle thing is still out of my understanding.

Comment: As the error says there is a problem with your manifest. Update the tags as per the suggestion. If that does not work post the stack trace here

Comment: can I suggest you mark your answer as an "Answer" so this question will be closed?

Comment: It says I can accept my own answer in 2 days. If someone can post the same answer I will take it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the problem with removing completely the label tags from the library wheel. Now the main projects builds and runs with no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Declare your manifest header like this

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackage"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">`

Than add to your application tag the following attribute:

```
<application
    tools:replace="icon, label"
```

For example I need to replace icon and label. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this solve an issue regarding my Manifest. I added
 `<application tools:replace="android:label"> ` and it fix my problem.

Comment: Works for me too. I was trying to add Countly sdk.

Answer (score 1):

> This Gradle thing is still out of my understanding.

You can continue to use Eclipse ADT as well http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/android/

Comment: Don't understand Gradle? Here's Gradle for Eclipse.