# Cannot find symbol variable R files - When I impor a project from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, import, ide

[Errors when importing a project from Eclipse to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322632/errors-when-importing-a-project-from-eclipse-to-android-studio#new-answer)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yourpackage"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Although I refer this method to modify my program, but it still got an error message 「cannot find symbol variable R files」.
Please let me know how to deal, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. Updating android studio fixed it for me. With some search others also claimed the same.